# iterate each object in array and populate each element of the array with result. asynchronously

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, loops, asynchronous

I need help with array asynchronous iterate functionality. I working with **node-opcua** library in **nodejs**. There is function **session.browse**(nodeId, result)
Right now code looks like:

```
NodesTree = {
        "NodesTree":{
          "name":"SYM:",
          "subf":[]
        }
      };
the_session.browse("ns=1;s=SYM:", function(err, browse_result){
                    if(!err) {
                      var buf = [];
                      browse_result[0].references.forEach(function(reference) {
                           if (reference1.browseName.namespaceIndex > 1) {
                             buf.push(reference);
                           }
                      });

                      NodesTree.subf = buf;

                      }
                    });
```

In result I get **references** of SYM: folder example:

```
[{"referenceTypeId":"ns=0;i=35","isForward":true,"nodeId":"ns=6;s=S71500ET200MP station_1","browseName":{"namespaceIndex":6,"name":"S71500ET200MP station_1"},"displayName":{"text":"S71500ET200MP station_1","locale":"en"},"nodeClass":"Object","typeDefinition":"ns=0;i=61"}]
```

I have Nodes structure in opc like this:

```
->SYM:
-->PLC
--->PLC_name
---->global_tag <variable>
---->global_tag1 <variable>
---->block
------>blok_tag1 <variable>
------>block_tag2 <variable>
```

Task is make one complete JSON object as tree for further use.

Logic is that: for each element in the **references** array get **nodeId value** and browse for **references** of the element and assign as element.subf = reference.

Final result something like:

```
    NodesTree = {
                "NodesTree":{
                  "name":"SYM:",
                  "subf":[
                       {attributes of PCL structure got by **browse**() + subf:[{ attributes of PLC_name by browse(), subf: 
[{....and here again attributes and subf] }, {if no subf just assign subf; [] }]


                   ]
                }
              };
```

So need call **session.browse()** for each reference and all finally bind to one object.

I tried to use **Async** library **each** and **map** in **series** functions to solve all that, but get nothing wise in result. May be there some smart solution can be found by Stack overflow community. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us your async code? This should work for your use case. You want a [map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map). First argument is your array, second is function retrieving the required content, and then in the final function you have an array of all results, which you then just need to concatenate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with `node-opcua` but assume that `session.browse()` is also async. Then something like this might work?

```
var async = require('async');

async.map(buf,
  function(reference, callback) {

    session.browse(reference.nodeId, function (err, result) {
      callback(err, result);
    });

  }, function(err, results) {

    // results is now an array of all single results
    NodesTree.subf = results;

  });
```

Comment: Actually, that helped me to solve problem. Code is more bigger than that but I got right direction) Thanks.